# IllegalArgumentException multiple json field name

Tags: java, android, json, arraylist, gson

I am trying to save an ArrayList to Shared Preferences in Java, but I am getting an Illegal Argument Exception:

```
 Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: class android.content.res.ColorStateList declares multiple JSON fields named mChangingConfigurations
                  at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.getBoundFields(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:170)
                  at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.create(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:100)
                  at com.google.gson.Gson.getAdapter(Gson.java:423)
                  at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.createBoundField(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:115)
                  at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.getBoundFields(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:164)
                  at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.create(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:100)
                  at com.google.gson.Gson.getAdapter(Gson.java:423)
                  at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.createBoundField(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:115)
                  at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.getBoundFields(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:164)
                  at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.create(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:100)
                  at com.google.gson.Gson.getAdapter(Gson.java:423)
                  at com.google.gson.internal.bind.CollectionTypeAdapterFactory.create(CollectionTypeAdapterFactory.java:53)
                  at com.google.gson.Gson.getAdapter(Gson.java:423)
                  at com.google.gson.Gson.toJson(Gson.java:661)
                  at com.google.gson.Gson.toJson(Gson.java:648)
                  at com.google.gson.Gson.toJson(Gson.java:603)
                  at de.onwukwe.chinaedu.remind.Start.start(Start.java:172)
                  at de.onwukwe.chinaedu.remind.Start.go(Start.java:138)
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                  at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:288) 
                  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6261) 
                  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:23748) 
                  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751) 
                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6776)
```

I just don't know what I am doing wrong. I have an ArrayList which stores Objects from type Dot:

```
ArrayList<Dot> generatedSequence=new ArrayList<>();
String json = new Gson().toJson(generatedSequence);
            editor.putString("GS", json);
            editor.commit();
```

This is  my custom class Dot:

```
public class Dot {



//unique ID of a dot, cannot be changed
public int ID;

//colour of a dot, can be changed through actions
String colour ;

//the real image on screen
ImageView dot;





//constructor
public Dot(int id, ImageView dot, String colour){
    Log.i("KonstruktorID: ", String.valueOf(id));
    this.ID=id;
    this.dot=dot;
    this.colour = colour;
    dotAppearance();

}

/**
 * This is a gettter method it returns the ID of the Dot
 * @return ID
 */
public int getID(){
    return ID;
}

/**
 * This is a gettter method it returns the colour of the Dot
 * @return colour
 */
public String getColour (){
    return colour;
}

/**
 * This method sets the colour of a dot
 * @param colour
 */
public void setColour(String colour){
    this.colour=colour;
}


/**
 * This method sets the appearance of a dot, so the colour and the size. It depends on the given colour and the current level
 */
public void dotAppearance(){
    //TODO add size changing
    switch (colour){

        case "yellow":
            dot.setImageResource(R.drawable.yellow_big_point);
            break;

        case "blue":
            dot.setImageResource(R.drawable.blue_big_point);
            break;

        case "red":
            dot.setImageResource(R.drawable.red_big_point);
            break;

        case "orange":
            dot.setImageResource(R.drawable.orange_big_point);
            break;

        case "pink":
            dot.setImageResource(R.drawable.pink_big_point);
            break;

         default:
             break;

    }

}

/**
 * this function should compute the color specific action of a dot and return the resultSequence
 * @return
 */
public ArrayList action(){

    return null;
}
```

The Dots are added to the list and then the list should be saved to Shared preference. But it won't work. When I am removing the generic Type Dot frome the ArrayList, the error does not occur, but this won't be a solution.
If anybody could help me that would be great, thanks in advance.

Comment: maybe you can add more detailed stacktrace so that we can help you better

Comment: Where are you using this field mChangingConfigurations ?

Comment: @nimi0112 I don't know where it is used. I am not using this variable in my Code, must be something on the GSON side

Comment: any fix here ? only happens on release build

Answer (score 1):

You should use Gson's `toJson(Object, Type)` instead since you're serialising an array list

More info here:
https://google.github.io/gson/apidocs/com/google/gson/Gson.html

Comment: even with this I am getting the same error.

Answer (score 0):

Don't do this, if there is the option of putting the ArrayList to a wrapper object.

So Json would become:

```
{
    arr: [
        ...
    ]
 }
```

And your ArrayList could come within a class. Of course as:

```
class Wrapper {
    List<Dot>arr = new ArrayList<>();
}
```

Raw lists are a bit tricky to handle with gson. And, shame on me, I can't remember on the fly.

Comment: still the same issue

Comment: Ok, next step might be introducing some better mvc. Maybe some class DotModel, that simply is the representation of your JSON. So before serialization you would have to map your List<Dot> to the DotModel list. class DotModel should not have a construtor btw. - or at least a default constructor.